# How to debug executable, built with catkin_make (without roslaunch)

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

in my project i built several executables with catkin_make and i want to debug it (e.g. with gdb). Usually when building with gcc one can just add the the argument -g. Is there similar why for catkin such that i can debug the executables afterwards with gdb and without using roslaunch?

I have tried starting gdb directly with the executable but it says `no debugging symbols found`.

I have also tried to do `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 -std=c++11 -march=native" )` without success.

I haven't found anything regarding this on the internet so far.
Thanks for helping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200155/how-to-debug-executable,-built-with-catkin_make-(without-roslaunch)/) by [Rufio](https://answers.ros.org/users/20729/rufio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want to take a look at [roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch Nodes in Valgrind or GDB](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB). Make sure to build proper Debug binaries.

Btw: this is not really specific to `catkin_make`. The `launch-prefix` just makes this convenient when starting things from launch files. For single nodes (and an already running master), you can also just do:

```
gdb --args /path/to/your/node/binary
```

> [..] I haven't found anything regarding this on the internet so far.

The tutorial I linked was actually the first result after searching for [ros gdb](https://www.google.com/?q=ros+gdb) on Google.

---

Edit:

> I have tried starting gdb directly with the executable but it says `no debugging symbols found`.
>
> I have also tried to do `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -O0 -std=c++11 -march=native" )` without success.

This has been answered before, see fi [Cmake debug option](http://answers.ros.org/question/155581/cmake-debug-option/):

> This will set -g for you:
>
> ```
> catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
> ```

catkin is just a thin layer on top of CMake in this case.

And if you need optimisation with debug symbols, see [catkin_make's option for optimization](http://answers.ros.org/question/172950/catkin_makes-option-for-optimization/):

> For a release configuration with opmizations and no debugging symbols, you can use the `Release` build type:
>
> ```
> catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
> ```
>
> For a release with debug configuration, with optimizations and debug symbols, you can use the `RelWithDebInfo` build type:
>
> ```
> catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
> ```
>
> CMake's [useful variables](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Compilers_and_Tools) page gives more information about build types.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufio](https://answers.ros.org/users/20729/rufio/) on 2014-12-29**:
thanks for the answer. I want to do it without using roslaunch because i have some unresolved problems with roslaunch (i will edit that in the title)
by using

```
gdb binary
```

i was not able to add some breakpoints and so on.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-29**:
If you use `gdb --args /path/to/binary`, gdb should start, but the binary should not be started yet. In this state you should be able to set breakpoints, and do anything you'd normally do with gdb. "I was not able to .." is a bit vague. If you update your original question, we might be able to help.